# How can use my if-else statements to take a specific action based on the input of the user's weight and then display it to the console?

Tags: c++, if-statement

```html
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

int main() {

 int weight; 
 string planet;

   if (planet== "Mercury")
       weight * 0.4155; 

    else if (planet== "Venus")
        weight * 0.8975;

    else if (planet== "Earth")
        weight * 1.0; 
    
    else if (planet== "Mars")
        weight * 0.3507; 
    
    else if (planet== "Jupiter") 
        weight * 2.5374; 
   
    else if(planet== "Saturn")
        weight * 1.0677; 
  
    else if(planet== "Uranus")
        weight * 0.8947; 
    
    else if(planet== "Neptune")
       weight * 1.1794; 
   
    else if(planet== "Pluto")
       weight * 0.0899;

    else (planet != "Mercury" && planet != "Venus" && planet != "Earth" && planet != "Mars"
     && planet != "Jupiter" && planet!= "Saturn" && planet!= "Uranus" && planet!= "Neptune" &&  
     planet!= "Pluto") 
          "Unknown Planet"; 
  

   cout << "Assignment 5" << endl; 
   cout << "The program is written by Micheal" << endl; 
  
    
   cout << "Please Enter Weight (as an integer of pounds): "; 
   cin >> weight;
   cout << "Please Enter Planet name (ie: Earth): ";
   cin >> planet;
   
   cout << "Enter entered a weight of" << weight << "and a planet name of" << planet << endl; 
   // cout << "On" << planet << "your weight in pounds would be" << 

  
         
  
    system("pause"); 
     return 0; 
}
```

Hello Everyone,

The purpose of my project is to take what the user's weight is and convert their weight to what it would be on a different planet and to have them enter the name of the planet. For example, if I weigh 175 pounds on Earth, I would weigh 72.71 on Mercury. 0.4155 * 175 and I already have all the other ratio calculations. But my question is how do I use my nested if-else statements to output the correct calculated weight to last line of this expression: cout << "On" << planet << "your weight in pounds would be"  <<. I have attached my C++ code above.

Comment: Move the if-elses below the `cin >> planet` and do `weight *= value` inside the ifs. Then just display `weight `

Comment: Can you further explain  YoTengoUnLCD?

Answer (score 2):

Your `if-else` statements are currently useless: they get executed before planet is initialized.

You should:

1. Read user input.
2. Modify weight according to the planet (`if`s go here).
3. Print modified weight.

Check your code carefully and you'll see where you go wrong.

You're also not updating the `weight` variable inside the ifs, which you should (or define a new variable `weight_at_planet = weight * 0.855`, for example), and print that.